# php redirect header location to phone number

Tags: php, redirect, mobile, mobile-browser, nokiabrowser

I'm trying to redirect the user's click on a link to a telephone number through php like this:

```
//HTML
<a href="tele.php">
```

and the php:

```
<?php
header("Location: tel:+123456789");
exit;
?>
```

This works on newer mobile browsers but won't on the older ones in particular Nokia WAP2.0 browser.
Any ideas, plaese?

Comment: Was there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution after few trials.

I set up a third-level domain of my main domain: `call.mydomain.it`.
In its docroot I placed an `index.php` file containing these lines:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['tel']) && $_GET['tel'] != "")
{
    $tel = $_GET['tel'];
    header("Location: tel://$tel");
}
die();
?>
```

So, when I load `call.mydomain.it/?tel=00393331234567` the browser starts a call to the number passed as argument.

Further on, if you have to setup a web marketing campaign, you can shrink this url with [this free tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/)

Hope having helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try `wtai://wp/mc;xxxxxxxxx` instead of `tel:`.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but i got an "Invalid web address" error from this.