# how to track click-to-call link on mobile site without javascript

Tags: php, mobile, href, tracking, click-tracking

What I want to do is count the number of clicks on this type of an image tel link:

```
<a href="tel:123456789"> <img src="images/myimage.jpg" alt="myimage" /> </a>
```

But my target platform - old Nokia phone browsers, does not support javascript so I've to use server side technolgies, namely php.

I'm hoping to integrate this with Google Analytics but if this isn't possible, that's fine as long as I can count the click and make the call simultaneously.

Comment: I speak under correction but I don't think you can do this without JS...

Comment: I tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293349/php-redirect-header-location-to-phone-number) initially but to no avail so I've sense changed my approach.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Analytics for Mobile Websites](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/other/mobileWebsites) documentation describes how to use Google Analytics without JavaScript, on the server side.